# How to solve $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\ ({\ln(e^x-1)}-{x})$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I tried isolating the x but then it turns from a $\infty - \infty$ to $0 \times \infty$ indetermination.

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\ ({\ln(e^x-1)}-{x})$$
Our teacher says we need to write all the steps so we can't solve it just with intuition (because of finals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x = \ln e^x $$
then
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\ ({\ln(e^x-1)}-{x}) = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\ ({\ln(e^x-1)}-\ln e^x) = $$
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\ {\ln\left(\frac{(e^x-1)}{e^x}\right)}
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\ {\ln(1-e^{-x})} = \ln(1) = 0
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Write $$e^x - 1 = e^x (1 - e^{-x})$$ and use the product identity for logarithms.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Succinct and pedagogical. +1.

Comment: @TatiiLourenco You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful!

Comment: @MPW Thanks, that was the intention!

Answer (score 1):

Hint take $e^x$ common so we get $ln(e^x(1+e^{-x}))-x$ then $log(ab)=log(a)+log(b)$ so we get $x-x+ln(1+e^{-x})$ so as x approaches infinity $e^{-x}$ goes to $0$ thus we get $ln(1+0)=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(e^x-1\right)-x\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\exp\left[\ln\left(e^x-1\right)-1\right]\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(1-e^{-x}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{e^x}\right)=$$
$$\ln\left(1-0\right)=\ln(1)=0$$